# Are Euler Bricks a Recursively Enumerable Set?

Tags: number-theory, computability

An Euler brick satisfies the Diophantine Equations:

$a^2+b^2=d^2$

$a^2+c^2=e^2$

$b^2+c^2=f^2$

Where a,b,c,d,e, and f are integers.

Has anyone proved the solutions are recursively enumerable?

Or does that fact that there are infinite solutions mean the set is not recursively enumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S\subseteq\Bbb N^6$ be the set of all sextuples $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ satisfying $a^2+b^2=d^2,a^2+c^2=e^2,b^2+c^2=f^2$. To show that this is a recursively enumerable set, we need to specify an algorithm which, given $a,b,c,d,e,f$ as an input, stops iff $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in S$. Consider the following algorithm:

`if(a^2+b^2=d^2 AND a^2+c^2=e^2 AND b^2+c^2=f^2)
   STOP
 else
   LOOP FOREVER`

(loop forever can be achieved e.g. by making the program execute one command without end)

It is clear that this algorithm will only stop if the tuple is in $S$. Hence we have shown that $S$ is recursively enumerable.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand what recursively enumerable is. Could you help? "There is an algorithm such that the set of input numbers for which the algorithm halts is exactly S". What is the algorithm, set, and S ?

Comment: I have rewritten the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: If you have time, I would appreciate you showing in the same way the set is "recursive"

Comment: What is your definition of recursive? I will expand this answer tomorrow.

Comment: well I think your answer explains that definition:"if there is an algorithm which terminates after a finite amount of time and correctly decides whether a given number belongs to the set." I am having a hard time seeing the difference