# Fairly simple problem: three integers, sums, and Pythagorean triples

Tags: algebra-precalculus, pythagorean-triples

So, I randomly thought about this simple problem, and **very sadly** couldn't make much progress in answering this.

> **Does there exist three integers $a,b,c\neq0$ where $a^2+b^2$, $a^2+c^2$, and $b^2+c^2$ are all perfect squares?**

---

**Here's what I've worked out:**

> Let $a^2+b^2=C^2$,
> $a^2+c^2=B^2$,
> $b^2+c^2=A^2$.

- For the smallest $a,b,c$ triplet that exists, *exactly one* of them must be odd.

  - It wouldn't be the smallest triplet if they're all even, and...
  - ...there doesn't exist a Pythagorean triple $x^2+y^2=z^2$ where both $x$ and $y$ are odd (so $a,b,c$ can't have more than one odd number).
- I've also found that $2(a^2+b^2+c^2)=A^2+B^2+C^2$, but this makes sense even when one of $a,b,c$ is odd.

I've even tried brute-forcing this with some code, but to no avail. So, I'm guessing there's no such $a,b,c$, but I haven't figured out how to prove that

---

So, it does seem that answering this would imply whether $a,b,c$ exists:

> Can $b^2+c^2$ be a perfect square if $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2+c^2$ are?

...which I haven't figured out either.

---

Maybe some *smart people* have already thought about this many years ago – if so, I'd be happy to see their work! *(Though, I've searched this up and found nothing.)*

Also, feel free to add/fix the tags (I only added two here). Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has been discussed already at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1964035p13594463). They have the name [Euler bricks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571383/are-euler-bricks-a-recursively-enumerable-set?noredirect=1).

Comment: Bruteforce from 1 to 250 is enough to say yes.

Comment: @DietrichBurde nice find! Also, I did search this up in the web (including here) and scroll down for quite a bit. Did you just search a related keyword (like Euler bricks) because you know it exists, or did you describe my problem (which is what I did)? 

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu you're right. The IDE I used earlier stops executing after passing the time limit **(and doesn't show anything!)** so this made me realize that 

Comment: I typed the three equations. But you are right, it took me while until "Euler bricks" came up. Anyway, I found it, so I hope  it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a system of Diophantine equations arises from so-called
[Euler bricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick), which are well known. The smallest solution is given by
\begin{align*}
44^2+ 117^2 & = 125^2,\\ 
44^2+ 240^2 & = 244^2,\\
117^2+240^2 & = 267^2.
\end{align*}